# Trouble preventing duplicate letter entry in pure JS hangman

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm coding out a hangman style game as is the custom when learning how to user JS. I have it working pretty well, but I cannot seem to figure out how to properly identify and prevent duplicate wrong guesses. 
Example: if you press "f" and it is not in the word, display and decrement the remaining scores once, and if you press "f" again, ignore the input. Here is my code thus far. I have my existing code in the function but it doesn't currently do anything. Any advice is appreciated.

```
 // words to guess will be selected from here
var wordSelectionArray = [
    "adventure", "bandit", "battleaxe", "battlefield", "beholder", "bugbear", "castle", "catapult", "cleric", "dragon", "dungeon",
    "fairy", "fireball", "giant", "goblin", "knight", "magic", "monster", "necromancer", "owlbear", "paladin", "potion", "quarterstaff",
    "sorcerer", "spells", "sword", "vampire", "warlock", "wizard", "zombie"]
    //variable to hold the randomly selected word
    var selectedWord = "";
    //variable to store number of blanks
    var blanks = 0;
    //var to hold the split out array of the randomly selected word. 
    var letters = [];
    //var to store blanks with the correct word
    var blankAndCorrect = [];
    //var to hold the incorrect letter guesses when input by the user.
    var wrongGuess = [];
    // start the game with a score of zero
    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;
    //variable to hold number of guesses remaining
    var guessesRemaining = 12;
    //array for guessed letters
    var alreadyGuessedLetters = [];
    //variable to hold the background music
    var myMusic = document.getElementById("background-music");

function game() {
    selectedWord = wordSelectionArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordSelectionArray.length)];
    letters = selectedWord.split("");
    blanks = selectedWord.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
        blankAndCorrect.push("_");
    } 
    document.getElementById("current-word").innerHTML = " " + blankAndCorrect.join("  ");
    myMusic.play();
    // console.log(selectedWord);
    // console.log(letters);
    // console.log(blanks);
    // console.log(blankAndCorrect);
};

//function to start the game over
function reset() {
    guessesRemaining = 12;
    wrongGuess = [];
    blankAndCorrect = [];
    game();
};

//check and compare function
function checkInput(letter) {
    letterInWord = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
        if (selectedWord[i] == letter) {
            letterInWord = true;
        }
    } if (letterInWord) {
        for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
            if (selectedWord[i] == letter) {
                blankAndCorrect[i] = letter;
            }
        }
    } if (letterInWord) {
        for (var i = 0; i < alreadyGuessedLetters.length; i++) {
            if (selectedWord[i] !== letter) {
                alreadyGuessedLetters[i] = letter;
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        wrongGuess.push(letter);
        alreadyGuessedLetters.push(letter);
        guessesRemaining--;
        console.log(alreadyGuessedLetters);
    }
};

//function to check wins/losses
function completeGame () {
    if (letters.toString() == blankAndCorrect.toString()) {
        wins++;
        document.getElementById("correct-answer-message").innerHTML = "Great Job! " + selectedWord.toLocaleUpperCase() + "  was the word!" ;
        reset();
        document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = " " + wins;
    } else if (guessesRemaining === 0) {
        losses++;
        reset();
        document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = " " + losses;
    }
    document.getElementById("current-word").innerHTML = " " + blankAndCorrect.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("guesses-remaining").innerHTML = " " + guessesRemaining;
};

game();

document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    var guesses = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    checkInput(guesses);
    completeGame();
    // console.log(guesses);
    document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = " " + wrongGuess.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how I'm ignoring duplicates in `checkInput`.

```js
// words to guess will be selected from here
var wordSelectionArray = [
    "adventure", "bandit", "battleaxe", "battlefield", "beholder", "bugbear", "castle", "catapult", "cleric", "dragon", "dungeon",
    "fairy", "fireball", "giant", "goblin", "knight", "magic", "monster", "necromancer", "owlbear", "paladin", "potion", "quarterstaff",
    "sorcerer", "spells", "sword", "vampire", "warlock", "wizard", "zombie"]
    //variable to hold the randomly selected word
    var selectedWord = "";
    //variable to store number of blanks
    var blanks = 0;
    //var to hold the split out array of the randomly selected word. 
    var letters = [];
    //var to store blanks with the correct word
    var blankAndCorrect = [];
    //var to hold the incorrect letter guesses when input by the user.
    var wrongGuess = [];
    // start the game with a score of zero
    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;
    //variable to hold number of guesses remaining
    var guessesRemaining = 12;
    //array for guessed letters
    var alreadyGuessedLetters = [];
    //variable to hold the background music
    var myMusic = document.getElementById("background-music");

function game() {
    selectedWord = wordSelectionArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordSelectionArray.length)];
    letters = selectedWord.split("");
    blanks = selectedWord.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
        blankAndCorrect.push("_");
    } 
    document.getElementById("current-word").innerHTML = " " + blankAndCorrect.join("  ");
    // myMusic.play();
    // console.log(selectedWord);
    // console.log(letters);
    // console.log(blanks);
    // console.log(blankAndCorrect);
};

//function to start the game over
function reset() {
    guessesRemaining = 12;
    wrongGuess = [];
    blankAndCorrect = [];
    game();
};

//check and compare function
function checkInput(letter) {
    if (wrongGuess.includes(letter)) { // <--- HERE
      // do anything else you wanna do
      return;
    }
    letterInWord = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
        if (selectedWord[i] == letter) {
            letterInWord = true;
        }
    } if (letterInWord) {
        for (var i = 0; i < blanks; i++) {
            if (selectedWord[i] == letter) {
                blankAndCorrect[i] = letter;
            }
        }
    } if (letterInWord) {
        for (var i = 0; i < alreadyGuessedLetters.length; i++) {
            if (selectedWord[i] !== letter) {
                alreadyGuessedLetters[i] = letter;
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        wrongGuess.push(letter);
        alreadyGuessedLetters.push(letter);
        guessesRemaining--;
        console.log(alreadyGuessedLetters);
    }
};

//function to check wins/losses
function completeGame () {
    if (letters.toString() == blankAndCorrect.toString()) {
        wins++;
        document.getElementById("correct-answer-message").innerHTML = "Great Job! " + selectedWord.toLocaleUpperCase() + "  was the word!" ;
        reset();
        document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = " " + wins;
    } else if (guessesRemaining === 0) {
        losses++;
        reset();
        document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = " " + losses;
    }
    document.getElementById("current-word").innerHTML = " " + blankAndCorrect.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("guesses-remaining").innerHTML = " " + guessesRemaining;
};

game();

document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    var guesses = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    checkInput(guesses);
    completeGame();
    // console.log(guesses);
    document.getElementById("letters-guessed").innerHTML = " " + wrongGuess.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<div id="current-word"></div>
<div id="guesses-remaining"></div>
<div id="letters-guessed"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to figure out!